# Get element from collection, depending on subcollection

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, collections

This is my class structure:

```
Public Class Product
    Dim productRef As string 
    Dim totalStock As Integer
    Dim sizes As List(of ProdSize)
End Class
Public Class ProdSize
    Dim stock As Integer
    Dim size As String
End Class
```

I had a selection of products stored in a `List (of ProdSize)`. I needed to extract the products with a stock value > 0. I got this with the following code:

```
FinalList = (From p In ProductList Where p.totalStock > 0 Select p).toList()
```

But now the requirements have changed and I need to get the products that have a `ProdSize` with a specific size and stock > 0.

For example:

```
Prod A, Size M, Stock 1
Prod A, Size S, Stock 0
Prod B, Size M, Stock 0
Prod B, Size S, Stock 1
Prod C, Size M, Stock 1
Prod C, Size S, Stock 1
```

I want to get Products A and C in my list `FinalList` when I look for size 'M'.

Is there a way of getting this with a single LINQ?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I need to use the properties of the class `ProdSize`: `stock` and `size`

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly, this should work:-`FinalList = (From p In ProductList Where p.totalStock > 0 AndAlso p.Size = "M" Select p).ToList()`

Comment: @RahulSingh, post it as an answer and i'll promise to upvote it ;)

Comment: @RahulSingh, this doesn't work. `totalStock` is the sum of all sizes. I need to use the properties `stock` and `size` from the class `ProdSize`.

Comment: @RahulSingh, i'm not a questioner ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos - Okay my bad! But OP's question is not clear thats why I posted it as comment.

Comment: @RahulSingh, you're right! The question was not clear. I will edit it right now, for future readers. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @RahulSingh, Keep calm ;) I've upvoted your answer, as i promised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I believe you are after:

```
Dim FinalList = (From p In ProductList
                 Where p.sizes.Any(Function(x) x.stock > 0 AndAlso x.size = "M")
                 Select p).ToList()
```

Although the "M" is hardcoded, I'm sure you could figure a way of removing this elsewhere.

Let me know if this works.

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
FinalList = (From p In ProductList Where p.totalStock > 0 
                        AndAlso p.Size = "M" Select p).ToList()
```

**Edit:**

The data which you gave doesn't seem to match with that of the classes which you gave, Although I have used that sample data according to your classes and wrote this in C# (Hope you can convert `Lambda` to `Function(x)` in VB):-

```
var FinalList = productList
              .SelectMany(x => x.sizes, 
                   (prodObj, Sizes) => new 
                               { prodObj.productRef, Sizes })
              .Where(x => x.Sizes.size == "M" && x.Sizes.stock > 0)
              .Select(x => new
                        {
                            ProductName = x.productRef,
                            Size = x.Sizes.size,
                            Stock = x.Sizes.stock
                         }).ToList();
```

Check this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BriATH), for sample data & query I have used.